# How can I make a ComboBox load content from a csv file, when a specific position in an opened picure is clicked on?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, fxml, javacv

Loading data from a csv file is not the problem here. My question refers to the MouseEvent which I need to load the data.
I have an ImageView which displays an image that was selected by FileChooser and a ComboBox which shall load some lines from a csv file when a mouse button is pressed on a certain position of the image (for example a rectangle, which I can easily check with mousePos.inside(rect) -> (Point mousePos = new Point((int) mouseEvent.getSceneX(), (int) mouseEvent.getSceneY()))).
Unfortunately I fail to connect the mouseEvent to my Combobox...
My current approach is this:

```
 public void annotate(MouseEvent me) throws IOException {
comboBox.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                 public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                     int mousePosX = (int) mouseEvent.getSceneX();
                     int mousePosY = (int) mouseEvent.getSceneY();
                     opencv_core.Point mousePos = new opencv_core.Point(mousePosX,mousePosY);
                     if (mousePos.inside(rect)) {
                         List<Person> personList = null;
                         try {
                             personList = CsvToList();
                         } catch (IOException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         } 
.....
}
```

.....
comboBox is my fxid which refers to my view created with an fxml file.
I guess that this is wrong and it would be very nice of you, if you could provide any help.

Comment: How about using `CombBox.setItems` or modifying the list returned by `ComboBox.getItems()`???

Comment: the combobox itself is not the cause of my trouble

Answer (score 0):

How do you think could your mouse pointer be somewhere over your image and over your combo box at the same time? Your approach does not make any sense.

Instead attach your event handling logic to the image view where it belongs and when you have then loaded your data attach the obtained list to the combo box.

Comment: makes perfectly sense... thanks :)  But unfortunately imageView.setOnMousePressed(......... does not seem to work :/

Comment: Without a simple, executable example it is difficult to help here. I have added the following statement in an application of mine which contains an ImageView and it works as expected. iv.setOnMousePressed(e -> System.out.println("Mouse was pressed on image view.")); So what is your problem?

Comment: Finally, I made it work. I had some issues with my fxml. But now thanks to your advice it is allright :)